# Selenium Clicks but Doesn't Select

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on making an automated web scraper run on Khan Academy to make offline backups of questions using selenium and a python scraper (to come later). I'm currently working on getting it to answer questions (right or wrong doesn't matter) to proceed through exercises. Unfortunately, selenium's .click() function doesn't actually select an answer. I think it has something to do with being pointed at the wrong object but I can't tell. It currently highlights the option, but doesn't select it.

[HTML for a single option (out of 4)](http://pastebin.com/RXwDUAAw)

I made some code to reproduce the error, and hooked it up to a test account for all your debugging needs. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# gets us to the SAT Math Exercise page
driver.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/mission/sat/tasks/5505307403747328')

# these next lines just automate logging in. Nothing special.
login = driver.find_element_by_name('identifier')
login.send_keys('stackflowtest') # look, I made a new account just for you guys
passw = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passw.send_keys('stackoverflow')
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]")
button[1].click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for things to become visible
radio = driver.find_element_by_class_name('perseus-radio-option')
radio.click()
check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Check answer')]")
check.click()
```

Comment: How about some html code?

Comment: The element is having a classname of "kui-button' Why not use just use this code to find the element driver.find_elements_by_classname("kui-button')]")

Comment: @JDelorean HTML added

Comment: @Ankur Gupta pointing to "kui-button" doesn't cause highlighting or selection.

Comment: What do u mean by highlighting.... It will click the element. I think that is the only purpose of yours

Comment: @AnkurGupta It doesn't actually click the way you can click with your mouse. As you can see when you run the program, the "Check answer" button doesn't light up until you click manually.

Comment: Its working with JAVA code :WebDriver driver_ome = new FirefoxDriver();
  WebElement we;
  driver_ome.get("https://www.khanacademy.org/mission/sat/tasks/5505307403747328");
     we=driver_ome.findElement(By.name("identifier"));
     we.sendKeys("stackoverflow");
     we= driver_ome.findElement(By.name("password"));
     we.sendKeys("passs");
     we = driver_ome.findElement(By.className("kui-button"));
     we.click();

Comment: I'd rather get it to work in python, but if I can't, I appreciate the Java snippet. Thank you.

Comment: I dont know why is thr the difference...If it is working for Java ...it should work the same for your python code.....

Answer (score 0):

After a trial and error process, I found that the actual click selection can be accomplished by pointing to the element with class "description"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# gets us to the SAT Math Exercise page
driver.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/mission/sat/tasks/5505307403747328')

# these next lines just automate logging in. Nothing special.
login = driver.find_element_by_name('identifier')
login.send_keys('stackflowtest') # look, I made a new account just for you guys
passw = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passw.send_keys('stackoverflow')
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]")
button[1].click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for things to become visible
radio = driver.find_element_by_class_name('description')
radio.click()
check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Check answer')]")
check.click()
```

For people dealing with similar issues, I would recommend clicking on the very edge of the space that allows you to select and inspecting the element there. This prevents you from accidentally using one of the innermost tags.